# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found:

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, entitymanager

I got the following code

```
@Stateless
public class BondecomandeDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Bondecommande findBCbyid(int id)
    {
         Query q =em.createNamedQuery("select bc from Bondecommande bc where bc.idbc = :idbc");
         q.setParameter("idbc", id);
         return  (Bondecommande) q.getResultList().get(0);
     }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bondecommande")
public class Bondecommande  implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="idbc")
    private int idbc;
    @Column(name="devise")
    private String devise;
    @Column(name="modepaiement")
    private String modepaiement;
    @Column(name="modelivraison")
    private String modelivraison;
    @Column(name="delaipaiement")
    private int delaipaiement;

      ////other attributes , getters and setters 
}
```

When I try to run the function `findBCbyid(int id)` I get this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Named query not found: select bc from Bondecommande bc where bc.idbc = :idbc

Although I used this named query in an another project, and it worked, what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `em.createQuery(...` instead of em.createNamedQuery()

If you work with named queries (what I would recommend) you have to place the query inside a @NamedQuery annotation on your entity class.

Answer (score 6):

In JPA query and named query are not the same things.

Named queries have "names" and you define them by adding `@NamedQueries` annotation on your entity type class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="bondecommande")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Bondecommande.findByIdbc", query="select bc from Bondecommande bc where bc.idbc = :idbc"),
    @NamedQuery(name="...", query="..."),
}) 
public class Bondecommande  implements Serializable {

    ....
}
```

You use named queries by passing the name of the query to create method:

```
Query q =em.createNamedQuery("Bondecommande.findByIdbc");
```

I recommend to use `TypedQuery<T>` not `Query` if you are using JPA 2.x

Answer (score 1):

`createNamedQuery()` takes a name of a query and not the query itself.

The Query can be defined by an annotation `@NamedQuery`
Take a look at this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I migrated working code from Java 8 to 17 (and also with 11). I was using EclipseLink (2.5).

The fix was to upgrade EclipseLink to 2.7 and it worked again.

Answer (score -3):

```
Query q =em.createNamedQuery("select bc from Bondecommande bc where bc.idbc = :idbc");
```

after `em.createQuery` here, and good