# exception NamedQuery of name JPQL

Tags: java, jpa

When I tried to execute this query, I got this exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   NamedQuery of name: odcalls.call not found.

This is my named query

```
 @NamedQuery(name="odcalls.call", 
             query="SELECT C.count(id)," 
                        + "C.date(CalllocalTime)," 
                        + "C.hour(CalllocalTime) from ODCalls as C " 
                  + "where "
                  + " C.date(CallLocalTime) between date_sub(curdate(), Interval 12 month) and date_sub(curdate(),Interval 1 day) : Date " 
                  + " and C.FirstQueue != 0 : String " 
                  + " and C.Calltype in (1) : int " 
                  + "GROUP BY C.hour(CallLocalTime), C.date(CallLocalTime)")
```

This is my DAO

```
     public class ODCallsImpl implements IDao <ODCalls> {
         EntityManager em = EntitiyManagerUtil.getInstance().getEntityManager();
         private List<ODCalls> calls = new ArrayList<ODCalls>();

         @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"  @Override
         @PersistenceContext
         public List<ODCalls> getAll() {
              calls = em.createNamedQuery("odcalls.call",ODCalls.class).getResultList();
              em.close();
              return calls;
         }
```

Comment: Please format your code (in Eclipse, select and `Ctrl + Shift + F`). Now it is absolutely impossible to read.

Comment: problem is when tired than stack overglow said 
×
Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: @user3656547 I've formated your text. I think that you can accept the changes.

Comment: Thank you Rubio for the formatting

Comment: You're welcome. I've just found this "Use em.createQuery(... instead of em.createNamedQuery(). " from the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497816/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-named-query-not-found

Comment: Where is your `namedQuery` defined? In your Entity class?

Comment: Nope @Entity
@Table(name="odcalls", schema= "`sogedes-db`") 
public class ODCalls { 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="ID")
 private String id;
 
 @Column(name="CallLocalTime")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) 
 private Date calllocaltime;
 
 @Column(name="CallType")
 private int calltype; This is my entity class. i also create setter or getter of this class

Comment: @Rubio I tired with  em.createQuery but this one is also not working its say Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [odcalls.call]

Comment: You're right. It was not the same problem. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your `@NamedQuery` in your Entity class.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="odcalls", schema= "sogedes-db")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="odcalls.call", 
             query="SELECT C.count(id)," 
                        + "C.date(CalllocalTime)," 
                        + "C.hour(CalllocalTime) from ODCalls as C " 
                  + "where "
                  + " C.date(CallLocalTime) between date_sub(curdate(), Interval 12 month) and date_sub(curdate(),Interval 1 day) : Date " 
                  + " and C.FirstQueue != 0 : String " 
                  + " and C.Calltype in (1) : int " 
                  + "GROUP BY C.hour(CallLocalTime), C.date(CallLocalTime)")
}) 
    public class ODCalls {  
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Column(name="ID") 
    private String id; 
    @Column(name="CallLocalTime") 
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)   
    private Date calllocaltime; 
    @Column(name="CallType") 
    private int calltype;
```

Comment: @ Patrick this code is not working. its say Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [odcalls.call].

Comment: @user3656547 do you want to create a jpql/hql query or a native query? If you want to create a native one, try it with this `@NamedNativeQuery`. If not, youre query is not valid

Comment: I want to create JPQL query.I think i have problem with parsing[odcalls.call]

Comment: @user3656547 For me your sql looks not like a valid jpql. Be sure that your query is a valid jpql. Instead you can thest the `@NamedNativeQuery` with your example query.

Comment: why it is not look like? this is my sql query and its work.SELECT count(id),
   date(CalllocalTime),
   hour(CalllocalTime) from ODCalls 
    where 
     date(CallLocalTime) between date_sub(curdate(), Interval 12 month) and date_sub(curdate(),Interval 1 day) 
     and FirstQueue != 0
     and Calltype in (1)
    GROUP BY hour(CallLocalTime),date(CallLocalTime) above is my JPQL query.If you find error please tell me

Comment: @user3656547  For example the keyword `interval`ist not valid in jpql I think.

Comment: Okay. I tired without keyword Interval but its gave me same exception.